# how to know what is soundcard name to increase volume level

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I'm having linux2.6.38 and I don't know what is my sound driver name to change sound level.When I write :

> [root@FriendlyARM /]# amixer -D pulse sset Master 50% ALSA lib
>   control.c:902:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL pulse amixer: Mixer
>   attach pulse error: No such file or directory

I have friendly arm embedded device with linux os.and this is amixer details:

```
[root@FriendlyARM /]# amixer
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 121 [95%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 121 [95%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone Playback ZC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [off]
  Front Right: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 121 [95%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 121 [95%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker AC',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 5
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker DC',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 5
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker Playback ZC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [off]
  Front Right: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM Playback -6dB',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mono Output Mixer Left',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mono Output Mixer Right',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Playback',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 255
  Front Left: 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Playback De-emphasis',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'None' '32Khz' '44.1Khz' '48Khz'
  Item0: 'None'
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 255
  Front Left: Capture 209 [82%] [7.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 209 [82%] [7.00dB]
Simple mixer control '3D',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 15
  Mono: 0 [0%] Playback [off]
Simple mixer control '3D Filter Lower Cut-Off',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Low' 'High'
  Item0: 'Low'
Simple mixer control '3D Filter Upper Cut-Off',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'High' 'Low'
  Item0: 'High'
Simple mixer control 'ADC High Pass Filter',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'ADC Polarity',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'No Inversion' 'Left Inverted' 'Right Inverted' 'Stereo Inversion'
  Item0: 'No Inversion'
Simple mixer control 'ALC Attack',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 15
  Mono: 2 [13%]
Simple mixer control 'ALC Decay',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 15
  Mono: 3 [20%]
Simple mixer control 'ALC Function',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Off' 'Right' 'Left' 'Stereo'
  Item0: 'Off'
Simple mixer control 'ALC Hold Time',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 15
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'ALC Max Gain',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 7 [100%]
Simple mixer control 'ALC Min Gain',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'ALC Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'ALC' 'Limiter'
  Item0: 'ALC'
Simple mixer control 'ALC Target',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 15
  Mono: 4 [27%]
Simple mixer control 'DAC Deemphasis',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'DAC Polarity',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'No Inversion' 'Left Inverted' 'Right Inverted' 'Stereo Inversion'
  Item0: 'No Inversion'
Simple mixer control 'Input',0
  Capabilities: volume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 63
  Front Left: 23 [37%] [0.00dB] Playback [on]
  Front Right: 23 [37%] [0.00dB] Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Left Boost Mixer Boost',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Left Input Mixer LINPUT1',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Left Input Mixer LINPUT2',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Left Input Mixer LINPUT3',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Left Output Mixer Boost Bypass',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 2 [29%] [-15.00dB] Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Left Output Mixer LINPUT3',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 2 [29%] [-15.00dB] Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Left Output Mixer PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'MIC Boost Gain',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 3 [100%]
  Front Right: 3 [100%]
Simple mixer control 'Noise Gate',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Noise Gate Threshold',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 31
  Mono: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'Right Boost Mixer Boost',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Right Input Mixer RINPUT1',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Right Input Mixer RINPUT2',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Right Input Mixer RINPUT3',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Right Output Mixer Boost Bypass',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 2 [29%] [-15.00dB] Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Right Output Mixer PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Right Output Mixer RINPUT3',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 2 [29%] [-15.00dB] Playback [off]
```

Comment: Linux 2.28? There's no such version of the kernel, which jumped from 2.6.X to 3.0.

Comment: sorry. I edit the post. you tell right I make a mistake.

Comment: it solve. I used [root@FriendlyARM /FGIT]# amixer set Speaker 50%+ and it works: but why its name is Speaker.`
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 127 [100%] [6.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 127 [100%] [6.00dB]
`